# Formula for SUMing certain months but disregard blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to total sales amount in a column for a certain month. The column with the dates will include blank cells.

I got this code to work once but when I try to change the sheet it references it just comes up with $0.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(eBay!$A$2:$A$3000),0,(SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(eBay!$A$2:$A$3000)=1)*eBay!$H$2:$H$3000)))
```

Where the Month Column is eBay!A2:A3000 and the sales column is eBay!H2:H3000.

I've also tried:

```
=SUMIFS:(eBay!H2:H3000, eBay!A2:A3000, (MONTH(eBay!A2:A3000)=1, eBay!A2:A3000, "<>")
```

I tried the Evaluate Formula for the first formula and it comes up as TRUE for ISBLANK when there are two cells with dates in them.

The second formula says the MONTH is 4 when there is a Month for January. So I changed the date from 1 to 4 and it didn't total for April either.

I thought either one of these formulas would work. What can I try next?

Comment: Can you post a data example? (input and expected output) are the dates being recognized as text or as date?

Comment: `SUMIFS()` will work for you. Check parameters, dates etc.

Comment: Try: `=SUMIFS(eBay!H2:H3000,eBay!A2:A3000,">="&41730,eBay!A2:A3000,"<="&EOMONTH(41730,0))`. Or instead of the `41730` reference a cell with the date 1st of april. If this wouldn't work my guess is you working with text values that look like dates.

Comment: The input data is 1/1/19 (set as date) and H column is dollar amounts.